# append to link and add css classes using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, lightbox

I am using the wordpress theme Enfold. I have a request from a client who wants a portfolio item to open in a lightbox , and then within that lightbox link to another lightbox for other portfolio item content. I can hard link the link in the portfolio item with ‘www.examplepage?iframe=true’ and it opens in a lightbox from the main page, but then the internal links will open in a second lightbox on top of the first.

My solution is to add the ?iframe=true to the link on the main page via jquery. I then make sure that the link has the required classes of ‘mfp-iframe’ and ‘lightbox-added’. However, even though in inspector all looks correct, the lightbox refuses to open using this method. I have added this using a plugin to add scripts to header and footer.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.lightbox a.grid-image').addClass('mfp-iframe lightbox-added');
$(".lightbox a.grid-image").attr('href', function(i) { return 
$(this).attr('href') + '?iframe=true'; }) 
});

});
</script>
```

The page shows the correct results in inspector:

```
<a href="/Winery/Giesen-Wines?iframe=true/" title="" data-rel="grid-1" 
class="grid-image avia-hover-fx mfp-iframe lightbox-added" style="height: 
auto; opacity: 1;">IMAGE INSIDE LINK</a>
```

But this still opens the link in a new page instead of in the lightbox.

This is the code from a working link generated by the theme:

```
<a href="/Winery/constellation-brands?iframe=true/" title="" 
data-rel="grid-1" class="grid-image avia-hover-fx mfp-iframe lightbox- 
added" style="height: auto; opacity: 1;">IMAGE INSIDE LINK</a>
```

They are the same.

EDIT:
The website is under development and so the real site can't be accessed by the public, but here is a test site with the exact same setup.

https://lionfishdesignstudios.com/skinsense/about/

On this page there are 2 different portfolio grids. The first one has the class 'lightbox' added, and therefor if you inspect it, the a link under the lightbox has the relevant classes added, and the link is myurl?iframe=true. The second portfolio grid doesn't have the 'lightbox' class and there has none of the added stuff.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a link to the website so we can test it?

I hope I am understanding problem correctly.

The issue is that the link inside the lightbox is not opening another lightbox?

its possible that the link the the 1st lightbox is not getting the click event because its generated via javascript and therefore not affected by the document.ready?

maybe try adding a .click() to your lightbox link so it works on elements that are generated

ex:

```
$(document).on("click","#test-element",function() {
        alert("click bound to document listening for #test-element");
    });
```

Comment: Hi Arron. Thanks for the reply. I've edited the initial question and added in a url where you can see the problem. My problem isn't inside the lightbox. The problem is that even though I think I have all the correct classes added the link won't open in a lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have it.
I needed to add .magnificPopup to the script. This is because of the theme Enfold and the type of lightbox they use.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

$(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.lightbox a.grid-image').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true
});

  $('.lightbox a.grid-image').addClass('mfp-iframe lightbox-added open-popup-link');
$('.lightbox a.grid-image').attr('rel', 'lightbox')
$(".lightbox a.grid-image").attr('href', function(i) { return $(this).attr('href') + 
'?iframe=true/'; }) 

});

});
</script>
```

The links now open in a lightbox without hardcoding the ?iframe=true to the end of the link in the portfolio.